# Concurrent HTTP request loop

Tags: php, performance, http, networking, concurrency

I'm using the [rolling curl](https://github.com/chuyskywalker/rolling-curl) library to fire HTTP requests for content-length headers of images (we need to know their size to weed out placeholders and low res images). The image URLs are stored in a database so I need to loop over the data in our products table (approx 1 million rows but will grow bigger, potentially much bigger).

I'm using PHP and the Laravel framework (the artisan CLI component). The operation seems to slow down as time progresses e.g. it starts processing 100 requests in less than a second and later the time to process 100 rows/requests is logged at over 20 seconds. Can anyone explain this and / or offer any performance improvement suggestions? The task is running on an Amazon EC2 micro instance so processing power / memory is limited.

```
public function fire()
{
    $dt = new DateTime();
    Log::info("started: ".$dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $counter = 1;
    Item2::where('img_size', '=', NULL)->chunk(1000, function($items) use ( &$counter)
    {
        $results = array();
        $filePath = storage_path().'/imports/new/new_img_sizes_'.$counter.'.csv';

        if (!File::exists($filePath)) {
            File::put($filePath, '');
        }
        $start = microtime(true);
        $rollingCurl = new \RollingCurl\RollingCurl();
        $rollingCurl->setOptions($this->curlOptions);

        foreach ($items as $item)
        {
            if ($item->img !== '') {

                $results[$item->id] = array('url' => $item->img, 'size' => null);
                $rollingCurl->get($item->img);
            }

        }
        //callback runs on each curl request
        $rollingCurl->setCallback(function(\RollingCurl\Request $request, \RollingCurl\RollingCurl $rollingCurl) use (&$results, $filePath) {
            $responseInfo = $request->getResponseInfo();
            //var_dump($responseInfo);exit;
            $length = $responseInfo['download_content_length'];

            foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
                if (array_search($request->getURL(),$value)) {
                    $idKey = $key;
                    $results[$idKey]['size'] = $length;
                    File::append($filePath,$idKey.','.$results[$idKey]['size']."\r\n");
                    break;
                }
            }

        })

            ->setSimultaneousLimit(10)
            ->execute();

        $counter++;
        echo 'done in...'.(microtime(true) - $start).PHP_EOL;
        Log::info('1000 records: '.(microtime(true) - $start));
        Log::info('Last url was: '.json_encode(end($results)));
        exit;
    }); // end item chunk
```

Some benchmarks:

> ```
> done in...3.8803641796112
> done in...7.4326379299164
> done in...8.1860301494598
> done in...8.5088090896606
> done in...10.606615781784
> done in...10.655412912369
> done in...10.804574966431
> done in...14.004528045654
> done in...10.903785943985
> done in...11.905344009399
> done in...13.763195991516
> done in...14.723680019379
> done in...15.823812961578
> done in...17.972007989883
> done in...31.734715938568
> done in...20.509822845459
> done in...22.924754858017
> done in...34.274693012238
> done in...39.217702865601
> done in...29.883662939072
> done in...24.094554901123
> done in...25.726534128189
> done in...31.788655996323
> done in...24.713880062103
> done in...25.855134963989
> done in...23.161122083664
> done in...32.380167007446
> done in...36.53077507019
> done in...31.859884023666
> done in...71.458341121674
> ```

Comment: Not to nitpick, but you have a very odd, if non-existent, coding style.

Comment: it's a very rough prototype. which has been hacked around while I get something working. Not sure it is 'nitpick'ing but it is certainly not constructive

Comment: I do apologize for lack of constructiveness, its just my pet peeve :) I actually don't see much you can do here, perhaps someone else can. Have you tried logging or lapping throughout the function to see if you're getting rate limited on the service side? Look up (https://github.com/jsanc623/PHPBenchTime) and use or copy the lapping function there to knock out rate limiting?

Comment: Actually, looking at it again - perhaps lower the concurrency that you set the second time from 100 (setSimultaneousLimit(100)) to 10 or less and see if this gives you better performance.

Comment: @jsanc623 How would the lapping function 'knock out' rate limiting? You mean rule it out as a source of the performance problem?

Comment: @jsanc623 I also couldn't get your PHPBenchtime working and logged an issue. It wouldn't work in Laravel via composer so I required it manually, then hit that error.https://github.com/jsanc623/PHPBenchTime/issues/4

Comment: Can PHP suffer from heap fragmentation, memory leaks, etc.? Might it work any better as a series of smaller/separate tasks?

Comment: @codecowboy - yes, meant rule it out as source of the performance problem when I said "knock out" rate limiting. I also updated PHPBT to fix the issue you opened ;) I'll have to update the composer.json and structure later on though so it can be imported via composer correctly

Comment: @jsanc623 cool, will help if I can. I'm getting some duplicates with the updated code above. Can you see what might causing it?

Comment: @codecowboy I don't see any duplicates? Also - seeing as there's a large jump of time towards the end, perhaps take ChrisW's recommendation and output memory_get_usage() along with time after each iteration?

Comment: @ChrisW: Damn right PHP can suffer from mem leaks... it manages its memory using simple ref-counts (if a `zval *` has more than 0 ref-counts, its memory isn't freed). If you want to leak memory, just have 2 objects reference each other: `$obj1->prop = $obj2; $obj2->prop = $obj2; unset($obj1, $obj2);` even though I unset both objects, they won't be freed

Answer (score 5):

I don't see what could be causing ever-decreasing performance since the only state outside the main loop is a counter, but adding calls to `memory_get_usage` as @jsanc623 recommends would help with that.

But you can definitely improve the performance by avoiding the loop over `$results` for every URL returned. Take advantage of PHP's array which is a hash table providing O(1) lookup.

First, make the URL the key for the results array.

```
foreach ($items as $item) {
    if ($item->img !== '') {
        $url = $item->img;
        $results[$url] = array(
            'id' => $item->id, 
            'url' => $url,
            'size' => null
        );
        $rollingCurl->get($url);
    }
}
```

Next, use `isset` instead of `array_search` and looping.

```
// foreach ($results as $key => $value) { ... } becomes

$url = $request->getURL();
if (isset($results[$url]) {
    $results[$url]['size'] = $length;
    File::append($filePath, $results[$url]['id'] . ',' . $length . "\r\n");
}
```

Since you're placing each URL into the array before making the GET request, the `if` isn't even necessary.

Separately, you can delay writing to the file until the end of the inner loop so you write one big chunk rather than one thousand tiny chunks. It may be that I/O is more costly, and perhaps you're getting killed by seeking to the end of an ever-growing file? Seems unlikely but maybe after a million writes it adds up.

**General Review**

There are a few things that could be cleaned up here as well.

- Consistent formatting: put your opening brace on the same line or the next, but do it consistently.
- Blank lines before the closing brace seem misplaced to me. Use blank lines to logically group related code, though functions are preferred to whitespace.
- Simplify testing if the image URL exists

  ```
  if ($item->img !== '')
  ```

  can be simplified to

  ```
  if ($item->img)
  ```

  to skip `null` values as well. Even if the field cannot be `null`, it's still easier to read.

Answer (score 4):

Be sure to disable Laravel's query logging and filter all unwanted results directly with your SQL query. Also use a stream to write lots of small chunks of data, it's much more efficient (and what streams where made for).

Here's a possible solution, would love to see the benchmarking results for this one.

```
<?php

class CodeReview {

  /**
   * Keep track of the Laravel chunk we're processing.
   *
   * @var integer
   */
  protected $counter = 1;

  /**
   * File handle of the current CSV file (writing only).
   *
   * @var resource
   */
  protected $fh;

  /**
   * Array to map image URLs to IDs.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $urlToId = array();

  /**
   * Used for caching only.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $storagePath;

  /**
   * ...
   *
   * @return this
   */
  public function fire() {
    // Directly format current time and embed variable.
    $date = \DateTime::format("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    Log::info("Started: {$date}");

    // Get storage path once (why is this even a function?).
    $this->storagePath = storage_path();

    // Disable Laravel's query log, otherwise it will eat up our RAM.
    //
    // @link http://laravel.com/docs/database#query-logging
    DB::connection()->disableQueryLog();

    // Execute the query and filter all unwanted results right away. Don't use closures because they are slower than
    // native methods.
    Item2::whereNotNull("img_size")->where("img_size", "<>", "''")->chunk(1000, array($this, "chunkedWhereCallback"));

    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Callback for the Laravel chunked WHERE query method.
   *
   * @internal Must be public in order to be accessible for PHP's call_user_func() function.
   * @param array $results
   *   The chunked results from the Laravel WHERE query.
   * @return this
   */
  public function chunkedWhereCallback($results) {
    // Open file handle to CSV file.
    $this->fh = fopen("{$this->storagePath}/imports/new/new_img_sizes_{$this->counter}.csv", "w");

    // Instantiate new rolling cURL and configure it.
    $rollingCurl = new \RollingCurl\RollingCurl();
    $rollingCurl->setOptions($this->curlOptions);

    // Micro benchmark
    $start = microtime(true);

    /* @var $result \Namespace\Of\Stub\Class\ClassName */
    foreach ($results as $result) {
      // Build hash array for easy lookup.
      $this->urlToId[$result->img] = $result->id;

      // Add this image to the cURL queue.
      $rollingCurl->get($result->img);
    }

    // That's it, we added all images to the array, let's fetch them. Again we use a native method and no closure.
    $rollingCurl->setCallback(array($this, "rollingCurlCallback"))->setSimultaneousLimit(10)->execute();

    // Finished handling chunk, close CSV handle and increase counter.
    fclose($this->fh);
    ++$this->counter;

    $end = microtime(true) - $start;
    Log::info("1000 records: {$end}");
    $last = end($this->urlToId);
    Log::info("Last URL was: {$last}");

    return $this;
  }

  /**
   * Write image size to CSV file.
   *
   * @param \RollingCurl\Request $request
   *   The rolling curl request.
   * @return this
   */
  public function rollingCurlCallback($request) {
    $size = $request->getResponseInfo()["download_content_length"];
    $url  = $request->getURL();

    if (fwrite($this->fh, "{$this->urlToId[$url]},{$size}\r\n") === false) {
      throw new \RuntimeException("Couldn't write to CSV file!");
    }

    return $this;
  }

}
```

- Format your code in a consistent fashion (stick to [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) rules if you're unsure)
- Try to document your code where it makes sense for you, or for a developer that might have a look at it later
- Closures hurt readability, maintainability and performance (some may disagree with this, but in your case they definitely do because they are too long)
- Return `$this` by default if you have no return value (like in jQuery) and allow chaining of all your methods by default
- Forget about type checks if performance is all you want (they only add overhead); but don't forget that they are great for public APIs and other stuff (like you get it if you use a framework), it makes things easier for other developers

Comment: your setCallBack fatals with Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to RollingCurl\RollingCurl::setCallback() must be an instance of Closure, array given

Comment: Never actually tried the code, how could I, but this means the RollingCurl has a really, really poor implementation of it's callbacks because it seems like it's checking the instance instead of `is_callable()` and using e.g. `call_user_func()`.

Answer (score 2):

Give this a try and post the results - it integrates PHPBenchTime laps and get_memory_usage() with your script.

```
require('PHPBenchTime.php');
use PHPBenchTime\Timer as Timer;

public function fire(){
    $Benchmark = new Timer;
    $Benchmark->Start();

    $dt = new DateTime();
    Log::info("started: ".$dt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
    $counter = 1;

    Item2::where('img_size', '=', NULL)->chunk(1000, function($items) use ( &$counter){
        $results = array();
        $filePath = storage_path().'/imports/new/new_img_sizes_'.$counter.'.csv';

        if (!File::exists($filePath)) {
            File::put($filePath, '');
        }
        $rollingCurl = new \RollingCurl\RollingCurl();
        $rollingCurl->setOptions($this->curlOptions);

        foreach ($items as $item){
            if ($item->img !== '') {
                $results[$item->id] = array('url' => $item->img, 'size' => null);
                $rollingCurl->get($item->img);
            }
        }

        //callback runs on each curl request
        $rollingCurl->setCallback(function(\RollingCurl\Request $request, \RollingCurl\RollingCurl $rollingCurl) use (&$results, $filePath) {
            $responseInfo = $request->getResponseInfo();
            //var_dump($responseInfo);exit;
            $length = $responseInfo['download_content_length'];

            foreach ($results as $key => $value) {
                if (array_search($request->getURL(),$value)) {
                    $idKey = $key;
                    $results[$idKey]['size'] = $length;
                    File::append($filePath,$idKey.','.$results[$idKey]['size']."\r\n");
                    break;
                }
            }
        })

            ->setSimultaneousLimit(10)
            ->execute();

        Log::info('Last url was: '.json_encode(end($results)));

        $Benchmark->Lap("Lap " . $counter . " mem " . memory_get_usage() . " bytes");

        $counter++;

        exit;
    }); // end item chunk


    $time = $Benchmark->End();
    print_r($time);
}
```

Comment: While this is probably a valuable answer, it does not provide a *review* of the OP's code. Please add more details, explain how this solution is different/better than the original code.

Comment: @lol.upvote Wasn't really meant as a full answer - rather just integrated memory_get_usage and a timer. I'd rather the code reside here than in a gist or a pastebin.

Comment: *I'd rather the code reside here than in a gist or a pastebin.* - and that's a good call, as a **link-only** answer would have been much worse. However **code-only** answers don't rank much higher. Feel free to edit whenever you have a chance :)

Comment: Please see [this meta question/answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1463/short-answers-and-code-only-answers) for more info.

Comment: Not to get in a spitting match here, but do note that I was commenting in codecowboy's question and this edited version of the code is requesting more information as I don't have access to codecowboy's environment. But if you'd like, I can make it a gist and just link it in a comment in their question.